# C# Pars html String mark text

Tags: c#, html, wpf, parsing

i want to pars a HTML string like:

```
<b><a href="/wiki/Schizophrenie" title="Schizophrenie">Schizophrenie</a></b> ist eine schwere psychische Erkrankung. Sie
```

or

```
    <h2 class="sectionedit2" id="zu_treffende_massnahmen">zu treffende Maßnahmen</h2>
<div class="level2">
<ul><li class="level1"><div class="li">An- und Abfahrtswege freihalten; Einweisung nachrückender Kräfte, evtl. Einbahnregelung vorsehen</div>
```

So that all the Text gets some extra font style elements (`<font style = "color:red;">..</font>`) like:

```
<b><a href="/wiki/Schizophrenie" title="Schizophrenie"><font style = "color:red;">Schizophrenie</font></a></b><font style = "color:red;"> ist eine schwere psychische Erkrankung. Sie</font>
```

or

```
<h2 class="sectionedit2" id="zu_treffende_massnahmen"><font style = "color:red;">zu treffende Maßnahmen</font></h2>
<div class="level2">
<ul>
<li class="level1"><div class="li"><font style = "color:red;"> An- und Abfahrtswege freihalten; Einweisung nachrückender Kräfte, evtl. Einbahnregelung vorsehen</font></div>
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Use http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to make a html viewer or editor - avalonedit can do that:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor

It has a syntaxhighlight definition for html already - really a nice control.

But if it is the challenge of doing it yourself - you can see how to start here:

http://khason.net/blog/richtextbox-syntax-highlighting/

Comment: I do not want to make a html viewer or syntaxhighlight. I ownly want to highlight all text parts in a html string. The Idea is to select some Text on a webpage and mark or highlight it in red. I have the Selection as a string and now i want to highlight the Text parts.

The Problem is, that the HTML can start and end in the middle of the page an a starting tag can be miss.